# iPhone not showing any option of sync

Tags: macos, itunes, data-synchronization, iphone

I have a iPhone 5 with iOS 6.1.3, I usually sync it with iTunes running on OS X 10.8.3 however for the last few days there is no option of sync , only the summary tab is shown and nothing else, please refer the screenshot, how can this behavior be repaired to what it used to be.

[image: Screenshot when iphone is connected to itunes]

Comment: Have you rebooted both your may and your iPhone already?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be corruption(I am not sure what else to call it) of file named iTunesCDB in iTunes_Control/iTunes directory in iphone's file system, I used iFunBox to do the delete that file, after that everything seems to sync well with no issues,

courtesy this [link](http://nethead.blogspot.in/2012/12/how-to-fix-itunes-cannot-read-contents.html)

Answer (score 0):

**Your iPhone is in Recovery Mode.**

Unplug it from your Mac/PC and exit the recovery mode.

Exit the recovery mode via:

> 1. Hold down the home and power button for about 15 seconds, this shuts
>      off the iPhone
> 2. Press the power button to boot the iPhone

Now it should be rebooting. Connect it again with you Mac/PC and fire up iTunes. Everything should work as it meant to be.

Comment: that didn't help, but following link did http://nethead.blogspot.in/2012/12/how-to-fix-itunes-cannot-read-contents.html

Comment: @VaibhavMishra, so your problem has been fixed? Would you be willing to post that as an answer here (link to the post, and summarize what steps you took to fix your problem)?